# Scrapy outputs blank (CSV & JSON)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a simple spider scraping some searchresults. Output works and it looks great, but when I try to export I end up with empty files. I know this is asked frequently but I cant seem to figure it out. I hope anyone can help me out.

Here is my spider!

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'gov2'
start_urls = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=a']

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="results"]').extract()
```

here is the code used for exporting!

```
scrapy crawl gov2 -o gov2.json
```

Also attempted CSV

```
scrapy crawl gov2 -o gov2.csv
```

And here is the output when exporting

```
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: gov2)
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.2.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 2.7.16rc1 (default, Feb 18 2019, 11:05:09) - [GCC 8.2.0], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Linux-4.19.0-kali1-amd64-x86_64-with-Kali-kali-rolling-kali-rolling
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'gov2.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'gov2.json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['gov2.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'gov2', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: a74692ba48906b88
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-03-14 10:46:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2019-03-14 10:47:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-03-14 10:47:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=a> (referer: None)
2019-03-14 10:47:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-03-14 10:47:02 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 541,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 57488,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 14, 14, 47, 2, 422730),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'memusage/max': 53796864,
 'memusage/startup': 53796864,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 14, 14, 46, 59, 955991)}
2019-03-14 10:47:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

EDIT: Added export code lines

Comment: Include the code you use for exporting

Comment: Done! thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You need to `yield` the values in your parse callback. Have you looked at the [official tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)?

Comment: NVM! I FORGOT THE COLLONS AROUND MY KEYWORD PRODUCT! DAMN THATS FRUSTRATING! THANK YOU VERY MUCH ANYWAY!!!!